# missing expression error

Tags: sql, oracle

Any reason why i'm getting a missing expression error?

```
select 
        CASE WHEN 
          (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
            FROM TRANSPLANT_ORGANS 
              INNER JOIN ORGAN_TYPE ON TRANSPLANT_ORGANS.TX_ORG_ID = ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_RECORD_ID 
           WHERE COUNT > 0
          )
      THEN
        (
             SELECT SUBSTR(CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID BETWEEN 660 AND 662 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/KIDNEY' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID BETWEEN 640 AND 650 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/LIVER' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID IN (620,622) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/PANCREAS' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID IN (621) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/PANCREAS ISLETS' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID IN (700) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/HEART' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID IN (600) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/LUNGS' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID BETWEEN 601 AND 607 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 2 THEN '/LUNGS' WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/LUNG' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID IN (680) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/INTESTINES' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID BETWEEN 685 AND 686 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'SMALL INTESTINE' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID BETWEEN 683 AND 684 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 'LARGE INTESTINES' END,
                  CONCAT(CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID IN (681) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/DUODENUM' END,
                         CASE SUM(CASE WHEN ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_ID IN (682) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '/STOMACH' END))))))))))),2,255)
            FROM TRANSPLANT_ORGANS 
                INNER JOIN ORGAN_TYPE ON TRANSPLANT_ORGANS.TX_ORG_ID = ORGAN_TYPE.ORG_RECORD_ID
        )
        END
```

Comment: Your `CASE WHEN` is incorrect.  The expression inside needs to be a boolean expression, not just a query.  Did you intend to check if the query returns any results?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are retrieving a COUNT from transplant_organs, but then never doing a comparison. `WHERE COUNT > 0` can be removed and then with the ending parenthesis you can put `) > 0`.

Second, your outer select doesn't have a FROM clause. At the very least use `FROM dual`.

Example:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM dual) > 0 
           THEN (SELECT 'Something' FROM dual)
       END
  FROM dual;
```